# What's the joke in Season 4 ep 8 of 30 Rock?

Tags: dialogue, 30-rock

In the streaming version of 30 Rock, there is missing dialogue. Season 4 episode 8, Secret Santa, Nancy Donovan, played by Julianne Moore, reunites with Jack and they recall old memories like 'Hey Beantown'. What was the wording of the joke about the larger classmate who breaks the pool?

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking what the exact wording of the joke was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen the show but the [online transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=30-rock&episode=s04e08) for that episode has the following:

> Bless her heart. She had a hypoactive thyroid.
>   **Do you remember the time she cannon-balled into Mel and Deschette's above-ground pool and tore the lining?** And floated out into the street! And got hit by that car? I have never heard you laugh like that before! That's how he laughs when he's really crackin' up.